# Concurrent put calls on a BlockingQueue in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, blockingqueue

I know that concurrent adds to an stl queue in c++ can cause issues, and the way to solve this is adding a mutex lock around all add/remove calls.

But I am programming in Java at the moment, and I'm using BlockingQueue. The documentation only says that the thread that calls put/take on a BlockingQueue object gets blocked implicitly until there's room to put/there's something to take respectively. However, it does not mention anything about concurrent put/take calls. Would I need to protect these with a mutex lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, blocking-queues are thread-safe. From [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html):

> BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe. All queuing methods achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms of concurrency control

Comment: I was a little unclear about that wording, so thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html):

> BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe.

Therefore, you don't need a lock.